# $watch on child element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-watch

I've been working on the directive 'input-container' where I need to add a $watch on the child's input ng-model. How am I supposed to do that?

```
<input-container>
        <label>Doc</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="model.userName"/>
</input-container>
<input-container>
        <label>Senha</label>
        <input type="password" ng-model="model.password"/>
</input-container>
```

I need to add different classes to my directive wrap depending on my input value. I added a watch like this

```
app.directive('inputContainer', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.addClass('input-container');

        elem.find('input').bind('focus', function () {
            elem.addClass('focused');
        });

        //---- code

        scope.$watch(???????, function (value) {

            if (value)
                //-- do something
            else
                //-- do something
        })
    }
};});
```

However I don't know how to watch my input ngModel. This was the only way I've found to get this working. Anyway, it doesn't allow me to access $viewValue

```
        scope.$watch(elem.find('input')[0].attributes['ng-model'].nodeValue, function (value) {
              if (value)
                //-- do something
              else
                //-- do something
        })
```

What I need is to get the input ngmodel variable dynamically, once it has different names for each directive instance, this way I could do something like this:

```
 scope.$watch(function(){
    return childInputNgModel.$viewValue;
}, function (newValue) {
    if (newValue)
        //-- do something
    else
        //-- do something
})
```

Comment: add more code please.. and elaborate more on it..

Comment: you can try using $watch('model.password', function(){});. I hope this helps, regards.

Comment: You can add an 'ng-change' on the input element.